How to sub select a column who is a CASE function in subquery?
i have a problem, i have an intern query who work data.
I want to format this data in a subquery but i am unable to select when the intern subquery use CASE...END functions.
See the exemple below
with TABLE_TIMER_EXEC as 
(
 select 1 as incrementer, 5393285 as time_stamp from dual union all
 select 2, 4009204 from dual union all
 select 3, 4533539 from dual union all
 select 4, 2188550 from dual union all
 select 5, 10577686 from dual union all
 select 6, 2495 from dual union all
 select 7, 734923 from dual union all
 select 8, 2188550 from dual union all
 select 9, 2115202 from dual union all
 select 10, 1730 from dual union all
 select 11, 3204559 from dual union all
 select 12, 4061501 from dual 
)
SELECT
   -- How can i SELECT quantum here??
   floor(TR.quantum / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) || 'd ' ||
   floor(TR.quantum / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24 || 'h ' ||
   floor(TR.quantum / (1000 * 60)) % 60 || 'mn ' ||
   floor(TR.quantum / 1000) % 60 || 's'
   as formatted_quantum
FROM
(
 SELECT
  Case When COUNT(incrementer) 
  OVER (ORDER BY incrementer ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) = 3 
Then AVG(time_stamp) 
  OVER (ORDER BY incrementer ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) 
End as "quantum"
 FROM TABLE_TIMER_EXEC
) TR

return : Error: invalid identifier 'TR.QUANTUM' (line 101)

Change as "quantum" to as quantum. fiddle (Also % is not the modulo operator. Use MOD(x, y) instead of x % y)

or use TR."quantum"

Or easier to read might be fiddle
